# Do you think having the asker information on top right would be better?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Like so:

[image]

How can I suggest this to responsible people?

Why I think this is better design is, this way the left side stays just about the question and the right handside is the meta of question. I think "Asked: today" and "Asked by: ..." are more related. So when I look at the card at the right handside, I would expect to see these information together.

Comment: You have another account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/1173112/koray-tugay

Comment: @Pang No I do not, the image is not from a question I have? Why do you think I have another account?

Comment: Consistency with answers?

Comment: Why do we care about consistency with answers? @DmitryKudriavtsev

Comment: If you look at an answer, the author is in the same place

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev I know that but why an answer format needs to be consistent with a question? Answer is a response to a question, it is not a form of question etc..

Comment: The author of the question doesn't really matter that much in the context of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange. Nor does it, arguably, matter that much *when* something was asked. Can you make a real case to the contrary?

Comment: @Pëkka Yes I can, I like to give more attention to questions asked by members with higher reputations. I think "when" it was asked is important too. What is the difference between a real case and just a case?

Comment: I think the question is more important than asker.

Comment: `I like to give more attention to questions asked by members with higher reputations` that's not really something the place wants to encourage.

Comment: @Pëkka ok, you win.

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking of compelling reasons to *not* do this, but I also have a hard time thinking of compelling reasons to not move *other* things randomly around the page, so that says nothing. More importantly, I can think of zero compelling reasons to move it. All other reasons aside, it is where it is, can you make a case for why it causes a problem where it is now? As it stands it appears you are looking for a solution to a problem that does not seem to exist.

Comment: See, you ask *"Why do we care about consistency with answers?"*, but I counter with: *Why do we want the left side to stay just about the question and the right side to be the meta of question?* (And, for the sake of argument, this grants the premise that the author card isn't "about the question", which I disagree with, but I'm sure other comments / answers here will cover that.)

Answer (score 4):

Right now, all important information is available in the left (main) column.  Views are nice occasionally, and "last active" can be helpful, but I also could have gotten those from the front page before clicking through.  So there's nothing *essential* in the right column, and I know I'm not the only user who routinely ignores it.

I disagree with your claim that the user isn't important.  We shouldn't be making decisions like voting based on who asked, and that's probably part of why the user is identified at the *bottom*, not the top.  But we should give attribution as clear as that given for answers, and the information in the usercard (and the hover popup) can be helpful.  Plus, frankly, if I see someone known to be an expert in a field asking a *question* in that tag, I know I'm going to learn something so I'll be more likely to read on.

You asked how to request a change.  To make a feature request, it's not enough to say "I'd like this"; you also have to make a case for it, including anticipating and accounting for objections.  This often proceeds in two (or more) steps, starting with a discussion question asking why something is the way it is or how people use a feature, and then later proceeding to a feature request informed by what you learned.